# I can't find qobject.cpp file on my computer.

Tags: qt

I can't find qobject.cpp file on my computer. I only can find qobject.h. But on my laptop I can. I don't understand what may be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may install Qt with or without sources, afaik. While headers are essential part of any library to be used properly, sources aren't required for the programmer to use a library. So maybe you've installed it differently on different computers.